# SQL CASE Variable

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to set this CASE statement as a variable but I'm getting the same date repeated in the column. This particular CASE statement is adjusting for daylight savings time. I use it throughout other queries but would like to shorten those queries by only having it once at the top as a variable.

```
DECLARE @newdate as Datetime

SELECT @newdate = 
CASE WHEN 
(a.REQDATE BETWEEN '2014-11-02' AND '2015-03-08' 
OR a.REQDATE BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2016-03-13'
OR a.REQDATE BETWEEN '2016-11-06' AND '2017-03-12'
OR a.REQDATE BETWEEN '2017-11-05' AND '2018-03-11'
OR a.REQDATE BETWEEN '2018-11-04' AND '2019-03-10')
THEN     CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,a.REQDATE),'-08:00'))
ELSE     CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,a.REQDATE),'-07:00'))
END

FROM TABLE a inner join TABLE b on a.REQDATE = b.REQDATE


SELECT
@newdate, b.REQDATE --control column
FROM TABLE b
```

Results:

```
(No column name)        | REQDATE
2016-04-08 13:00:52.000 | 2015-11-02 15:41:25.000   
2016-04-08 13:00:52.000 | 2016-02-02 10:25:54.000   
2016-04-08 13:00:52.000 | 2016-02-11 12:59:10.000
```

Let me add some more info to this. I want to replace the following code:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (b.REQDATE BETWEEN '2014-11-02' AND '2015-03-08' 
OR b.REQDATE BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2016-03-13'
OR b.REQDATE BETWEEN '2016-11-06' AND '2017-03-12'
OR b.REQDATE BETWEEN '2017-11-05' AND '2018-03-11'
OR b.REQDATE BETWEEN '2018-11-04' AND '2019-03-10')
THEN     CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,b.REQDATE),'-08:00'))
ELSE CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,b.REQDATE),'-07:00')) END         AS "DateOpened"
FROM TABLE
```

With this:

```
SELECT
@newdate
FROM TABLE
```

Basically creating a variable out of the CASE statement

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you are asking. What is your question specifically?

Comment: `@newdate` is a single valued variable. It cannot hold multiple values.

Answer (score 3):

A variable can only hold one value. What you need to do is move that case statement into a function...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DST(@d datetime) 
RETURNS datetime 
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN 
    (@d BETWEEN '2014-11-02' AND '2015-03-08' 
    OR @d BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2016-03-13'
    OR @d BETWEEN '2016-11-06' AND '2017-03-12'
    OR @d BETWEEN '2017-11-05' AND '2018-03-11'
    OR @d BETWEEN '2018-11-04' AND '2019-03-10')
    THEN     CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,@d),'-08:00'))
    ELSE     CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,@d),'-07:00'))
    END
END
GO
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5adff/1)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of @newDate variable, declare a temp table and insert records into that. Once done, just inner join the new table data with table b or any other table where you need to correlate and get your results.